# Theorem: How to use Chinese Remainder Theorem to find solution of modular system of congruences.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm working on a problem where I have an equation such as

$y = x ^ d \pmod M$

where $M$ is a product of unique primes; each prime is denoted by $M_i$, where $i$ is less than an integer $l$.

In the above equation, I am trying to solve for $y$. I know $x$ and $M$ (and all $M_i$ values that make up $M$). I do not know $d$, but I know all values of $d_i$, where $d_i = d \pmod {M_i - 1}$. Furthermore, $d = e^{-1} \pmod {\phi(M)}$, and $e$ is an integer such that $\gcd(\phi(M), e) = 1$ and $e < \phi(M)$. The method I need to follow is:

1. Calculate     $(y_i) = x^{d_i}  \pmod{ M_i}$, where I know all $d_i$ and $M_i$.
2. Once I have all $y_i$ values for how many ever primes there are (number of $M_i$'s), I need to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to 'combine' all $y_i$ values to achieve $y$.

I'm unsure of how to go about doing this. I can find $y_i$ values, which I have already done. What do I need to do to combine them?

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: This is not clear.  I assume that you seek to avoid working $\pmod M$ because $M$ is impractically large?  But, are we to assume that each of the distinct prime powers that comprise $M$ is not also impractically large?

Comment: The exact reason why I am breaking it up is because I do not know d, but I know all d_i values.

Comment: Ah. But you failed to define the $d_i$.  And you specifically say that you do know $d$.

Comment: d_i = d (mod (M_i - 1)) for every M_i, where d = e ^-1 (mod (EulerTotient(M))) and GCD(e, EulerTotient(M)) = 1.

I'm just struggling on how to combine the results. I know that all the previous work is correct.

Comment: What is $M_i$?  Please edit your post for clarity.  You specifically wrote that "I know x, d, and M" but I guess you didn't mean that?  Anyway, please edit to indicate clearly what the given information is.

Comment: Edited; hopefully that is better?

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that $M$ is the product of distinct primes?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit that in. Sorry about that. Edited it in. Is that better?

Comment: But in that case, what's the problem?  You can work out $x^{d_i} \pmod {M_i}$ for each $i$ and then use the standard CRT algorithms to combine the solutions (which are guaranteed to be relatively prime as they are distinct primes).

Comment: Yes, but I'm still a little confused on how to go about doing so; are there any hints to nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: The standard algorithm:  If we know $A=a_1\pmod n$ and $A=a_2\pmod m$ where $n,m$ are relatively prime then use the first to write $A=a_1+tn$ and then solve $a_1+tn\equiv a_2\pmod m$ for $t$.    Repeat as often as needed.

Comment: So in my case, I have calculated A? Since I calculate each m_i?

So I have m_1, m_2, and m_3 calculated for example.

Comment: In your post, you claim that you know all the $a_i$ and you seek to find $A$.

Comment: Specifically, $a_i\equiv x^{d_i}\pmod {M_i}$.  And your goal is to find a single residue $\pmod M$ which is congruent to each of these.

Comment: Right, so the comment you just made makes sense to me. I have all a_i calculated out, since I know x, d_i, and M_i.

Comment: Exactly.  This is a fairly standard method for working CRT problems explicitly.  You just do one factor at a time.

Comment: Okay so once I get the t values, what do I do with them?

Comment: In my notation, if you know $t$ then you know $A\pmod {nm}$  so then you can move to the next relatively prime factor.

Comment: Right... I guess I'm just a littlle confused on what t actually is. Once I solve for t with respect to n and m, what does t signify?

Comment: Say $t \equiv 7\pmod m$.  Then we know $A=a_1+(7+km)n\equiv a_1+7n\pmod {mn}$.  So now we know $A\pmod {mn}$.  You can now move to the next relatively prime term.

Comment: But, honestly, the CRT is pretty basic stuff.  You should study that before you worry about exponentials and such.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for all your help.